# How expensive are `count` calls for Django querysets?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-orm

I have a list of "posts" I have to render. For each post, I must do three filter querysets, OR them together, and then count the number of objects. Is this reasonable? What factors might make this slow?

This is roughly my code:

```
def viewable_posts(request, post):

    private_posts = post.replies.filter(permissions=Post.PRIVATE, author_profile=request.user.user_profile).order_by('-modified_date')
    community_posts = post.replies.filter(permissions=Post.COMMUNITY, author_profile__in=request.user.user_profile.following.all()).order_by('-modified_date')
    public_posts = post.replies.filter(permissions=Post.PUBLIC).order_by('-modified_date')

    mixed_posts = private_posts | community_posts | public_posts

    return mixed_posts

def viewable_posts_count(request, post):

    return viewable_posts(request, post).count()
```

Comment: please post some code: the models, the queries. "Slow" is a question of indexing, roundtrips to the DB, how much data has to go from the DB to the web server, etc. It's very specific

Comment: Err, I added, roughly, the view code. The model is pretty obvious I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest factor I can see is that you have filter actions on each post. If possible, you should query the results associated with each post in ONE query. As of the `count`, it's the most efficient way of getting the number of results from a query, so it's likely not a problem.

Comment: If I OR the query sets before I execute the query, does that count as one query?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
def viewable_posts(request, post):

    private_posts = post.replies.filter(permissions=Post.PRIVATE, author_profile=request.user.user_profile).values_list('id',flat=True)
    community_posts = post.replies.filter(permissions=Post.COMMUNITY, author_profile__in=request.user.user_profile.following.values_list('id',flat=True)
    public_posts = post.replies.filter(permissions=Post.PUBLIC).values_list('id',flat=True)

   Lposts_id = private_posts
   Lposts_id.extend(community_posts)
   Lposts_id.extend(public_posts)

   viewable_posts  = post.filter(id__in=Lposts_id).order_by('-modified_date')
   viewable_posts_count  = post.filter(id__in=Lposts_id).count()

   return viewable_posts,viewable_posts_count
```

It should improve the following things:

1. order_by once, instead of three times
2. The count method runs on a query with only the index field
3. django uses a faster filter with "values", both for the count and the filtering.
4. Depends on your database, the db own cache may pick the last queried posts for viewable_posts, and use it for viewable_posts_count

Indeed, if you can squeeze the first three filter queries into one, you will save time as well.